# Save the Row data in Table using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi Here I am trying to save the data which user enter in a table. I have written Javascript for this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function Savefile() {

            var tbl = document.getElementById("modaltable");
            var final = " ";
            var finalvalue = " ";
            if (tbl != null) {
                for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
                        var text = document.getElementById("Comment").value;
                        var typeofscram = document.getElementById("<%=DropDownList2.ClientID %>").value;
                        var scramblerreq = document.getElementById("<%=DropDownList1.ClientID %>").value;
                        var final = text + " " + typeofscram + " " + scramblerreq;

                    }
                    finalvalue += final;
                }
            }
            var myCsv = finalvalue;
            window.open('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(myCsv));

        }
    </script>
```

But it is saving only first row values. But I need to save the remaining row values also. In second row also it is saving first row details.Any mistake in above code.

Comment: Add your html code snippets for clarification

Comment: document.getElementById("Comment").value; this is what wrong in your code. You need to replace this block by searching through tbl.rows[i].cells[j]

Comment: can you please console and check the value of tbl.rows.length